# jhipster Oracle database connectivity

Tags: oracle, liquibase, jhipster

I can't seem to get the Liquibase running against oracle.

My application-dev.yml has:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
    username: rest_test
    password: rest_test

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
    database: ORACLE
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
    ddl-auto: none
```

But I recieved:

```
[DEBUG] com.steve.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[ERROR] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter - Property url is does not exist on target    class class oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

Which is odd as the class seems to have a url property:

```
[btuser@localhost pool]$ strings OracleDataSource.class | grep -i seturl
setURL
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

fixed this now, this config now works:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dataSourceClassName: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
    username: rest_test
    password: rest_test

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    database: ORACLE
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

Comment: latest jhipster (3.4.1+) doesn't require these changes anymore-